# High level command line program for burning CDs and DVDs?

Tags: linux, command-line, dvd, burning, compact-disc

I'm sick of screwing around trying to script a clean solution to burn multiple files and folders to CDs and DVDs with `wodim`, `growisofs` and `genisoimage`.

I'm looking for a high level command line program that uses sensible defaults and takes arguments something like this:

```
[program-name] [cd|dvd] /path/to/dir1/ /path/to/dir2/ /path/to/file ...
```

It should then do all the low level copying and ISO generation transparently and just burn the damn disk!

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've looked at several programs but it seems there are too many choices to trawl through and not enough information about them online.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it seems like there **is** no clear winner. I've ended up scripting it using `growisofs` with the `--graft-points` option, something like this:

```
for FILE in $FILES
do
    GRAFT_POINTS="$GRAFT_POINTS $FILE=$FILE"
done
growisofs -dvd-compat -input-charset=ISO-8859-1 -Z $DVD_DRIVE -R -J -pad --graft-points $GRAFT_POINTS
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want [cdrecord](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/man/cdrecord/cdrecord.1.html) from [cdrtools](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/cdrecord.html)

You use it like this

```
cdrecord /dev/cdrom /path/to/track1 /path/to/track2 ...
```

That is a pretty close match to what you have asked for.

Comment: The OP said he/she was tired of `wodim` which is a fork of `cdrecord`, so it may not be quite what they want.

Comment: I've had a look at cdrecord, and apart from the fact that it doesn't burn DVDs, it seems like each data 'track' you specify must already be either an ISO-9660 or Rock Ridge filesystem image. This means generating ISOs first using `genisoimage`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [bashburn](http://bashburn.dose.se/).

It is a frontend to CLI tools.

Comment: I haven't installed bashburn to test it, but it looks like it's interactive (uses ncurses or something) - I want something I can run just by passing it arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CdDvd/Burning#Burning%20a%20CD%20or%20DVD%20using%20Command%20Line%20tools) for Ubuntu ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know how to burn from the command line, I just find the syntax too verbose.